# Decrypt CVV from Wallester API

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I am trying to decrypt the CVV that i receive from wallester api, but i get an error and i don't know why. I have no problem interacting with the API, I get the correct encrypted CVV, but I can't decrypt it. Here is my code:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64

encoded_cvv = """-----BEGIN CardNumber MESSAGE-----
<base64 encoded string>
-----END CardNumber MESSAGE-----"""

b64_decoded = base64.b64decode(
    encoded_cvv.replace("\n", "").
    replace("-----BEGIN CardNumber MESSAGE-----", "").
    replace("-----END CardNumber MESSAGE-----", "")
)

private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private_key.pem").read())
decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)

print(decryptor.decrypt(b64_decoded))
```

I'm always getting ValueError: `Incorrect decryption`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's also facing this problem: I managed to successfully decrypt the string by specifying label and hashAlgo:

```py
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

...

decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key, label=b"CardNumber", hashAlgo=SHA256)
# ^^^
```